# Sequelize associations not grouping properly

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, feathersjs

Working on a feathersJS app using the generator. When attempting to set up model associations with sequelize, the fetched data is not structured that way I would expect it to be.

I have read a ton of the sequelize documentation, but am unable to find the correct way to tell sequelize to structure the code as an array.

Here is the relevant code I am working with.

cars.model.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const cars = sequelizeClient.define('cars', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  cars.associate = function (models) {
    models.cars.hasMany(models.tires, { as: 'tires'});
  };

  return cars;
};
```

tires.model.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const tires = sequelizeClient.define('tires', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    car_id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    position: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  tires.associate = function (models) {
    models.tires.belongsTo(models.cars);
  };

  return tires;
};
```

and this is the hook I created to define the includes. It is set up in the 'before' hook for 'find' and 'get' queries.
include-car-tires.js

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) {
  return async context => {

    if (context.params.query.include) {
      const TiresModel = context.app.services.tires.Model;
      context.params.sequelize = {
         include: [{
             model: TiresModel,
             as: 'tires'
         }]
      };
      delete context.params.query.include;
    }

    return context;
  };
};
```

what I am getting...

```
{
    "total":2,
    "limit":10,
    "skip":0,
    "data":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"sally",
            "type":"mustang",
            "tires.id":1,
            "tires.car_id":1,
            "tires.type":"slick",
            "tires.position":"front right"
        },
        {
            "id":1,"name":"sally",
            "type":"mustang",
            "tires.id":2,
            "tires.car_id":1,
            "tires.type":"slick",
            "tires.position":"front left"
        },
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"sally",
            "type":"mustang",
            "tires.id":3,
            "tires.car_id":1,
            "tires.type":"slick",
            "tires.position":"rear right"
        },
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"sally",
            "type":"mustang",
            "tires.id":4,
            "tires.car_id":1,
            "tires.type":"slick",
            "tires.position":"rear left"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"herby",
            "type":"beetle",
            "tires.id":5,
            "tires.car_id":2,
            "tires.type":"winter",
            "tires.position":"front right"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"herby",
            "type":"beetle",
            "tires.id":6,
            "tires.car_id":2,
            "tires.type":"winter",
            "tires.position":"front left"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"herby",
            "type":"beetle",
            "tires.id":7,
            "tires.car_id":2,
            "tires.type":"winter",
            "tires.position":"rear right"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"herby",
            "type":"beetle",
            "tires.id":8,
            "tires.car_id":2,
            "tires.type":"winter",
            "tires.position":"rear left"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am expecting...

```
{
    "total":2,
    "limit":10,
    "skip":0,
    "data":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"sally",
            "type":"mustang",
            "tires:[
                {
                    "id":1,
                    "car_id":1,
                    "type":"slick",
                    "position":"front right"
                },
                {
                    "tires.id":2,
                    "tires.car_id":1,
                    "tires.type":"slick",
                    "tires.position":"front left"
                },
                {
                    "tires.id":3,
                    "tires.car_id":1,
                    "tires.type":"slick",
                    "tires.position":"rear right"
                },
                {
                    "tires.id":4,
                    "tires.car_id":1,
                    "tires.type":"slick",
                    "tires.position":"rear left"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"herby",
            "type":"beetle",
            "tires:[
                {
                    "id":5,
                    "car_id":2,
                    "type":"winter",
                    "position":"front right"
                },
                {
                    "tires.id":6,
                    "tires.car_id":2,
                    "tires.type":"winter",
                    "tires.position":"front left"
                },
                {
                    "tires.id":7,
                    "tires.car_id":2,
                    "tires.type":"winter",
                    "tires.position":"rear right"
                },
                {
                    "tires.id":8,
                    "tires.car_id":2,
                    "tires.type":"winter",
                    "tires.position":"rear left"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize#sequelize-raw-queries

Comment: You are missing a `raw: true` somewhere.